# Nested Sequence of Closed Bounded Sets in a Complete Metric Space

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification, metric-spaces

> Let $\{E_n\}$ be a sequence of closed bounded sets in a complete metric space $X$, such that $E_{n+1} \subset E_n$, for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, and $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} $diam $E_n=0$. Prove that $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} E_n$ contains exactly one point.

**Proof:**

Let $E= \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} E_n$; by definition, for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $E \subset E_n$ and so diam $E \leq$ diam$E_n$. Since, diam $E_n \to 0$, assuming $\lvert E \rvert > 1$ leads to a contradiction. So, the proof reduces to showing that $E$ is not empty.

Edit: Note that we assume the $E_n$ are all non-empty. Further, if any $\lvert E_k \rvert =1$, the result follows immediately, so, for all $E_n$, we assume $\lvert E_n \rvert > 1$.

For any $E_n$, there exists $q_n \in E_n$ and a smallest real number $M_n>0$, such that $$d(p, q_n) \leq M_n, \qquad \forall p \in E_n.$$

Since we must have $M_n \to 0$, for any $\epsilon >0$, there exists an integer $N$ such that 
$$d(q_n, q_m) \leq d(q_n, p) + d(p, q_m)< M_N + M_N< \epsilon,$$
for all $n \geq N, m \geq N$ (by an appropriate choice of $p$).
The sequence of points $\{q_n\}$ is thus a Cauchy sequence in $X$, and so it converges to some point $q \in X$.

For some $K \in \mathbb{N}$, assume $q$ is not a point in $E_K$, then $q \notin E_n$ for all $n \geq K$. It also follows that $q$ is not a limit point for $E_K$, and so there exists $\epsilon>0$, such that 
$$p \notin N_\epsilon (q), \quad \forall p\in E_K.$$

The convergence of $\{q_n\}$ implies that there exists an integer $m > K $ such that 
$$d(q_m, q)< \epsilon,$$
but
$$E_m \subset E_K \implies q_m \in E_K,$$
which is a contradiction. Thus $q \in E$. $\qquad \square$

**Question:**
Is there an additional assumption in the problem that the $E_n$ are all non-empty (since the empty set is closed,  bounded, and is its own subset)?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Must the $E_n$ be nonempty? Sure, otherwise the intersection is empty (and the empty set is bounded, closed and has diametre zero).

Comment: Your proof breaks down when you say "there exists $q_n \in E_n$"

Comment: @WillM. Thanks, it just wasn’t explicitly stated in the problem and so I wasn’t sure if the given conditions implied that each $E_n$ had to be non-empty.

Comment: @mathworker21 Really? Isn’t the existence of such a $q_n$ implied by boundedness?

Comment: @MoedPolBollo: No. An empty set is vacuously bounded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assumption that the $E_n$ are non-empty might be hidden in the assumption about their diameter, depending on your definitions. Usually if $E$ is a subset of a metric space $(M,d)$, we denote:

$$
\operatorname{diam} E = \sup \{ d(x,y) : x, y \in E \}
$$

If, however, $E$ is empty, then we are taking the supremum of the empty set. This is usually defined to be $-\infty$. So, if one of the $E_n$ is empty, then all of the following sets are too, which means that the limit of their diameters would be $-\infty$: a contradiction to the assumption.

However, this does rely on this particular definition of the supremum. Usually, it's best to be clear and explicitly state the $E_n$ are non-empty.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn’t aware of that definition.

Comment: No problem! Don't forget, though, that definitions are arbitrary, and some people may disagree with this definition. The important thing is to be clear about what you're stating.